# string interpretation in conditional statements

Tags: mysql, string

How does mysql cast string to boolean when they are used  in conditional statements?

```
select if("192.168.0.0",true,false) // returns 1
select if("-1",true,false) // returns 1
select if("a1",true,false) // returns 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL uses C-style booleans: `0` is false and any other number is true. So, the real question is:

> How does MySQL cast a string to a number?

The answer to that is that it converts the strings in the obvious way, it goes from left to right and stops parsing when it no longer has a valid number. For example:

```
mysql> select '192.168.0.0' + 0, '-1' + 0, 'pancakes11' + 0;
+-------------------+----------+------------------+
| '192.168.0.0' + 0 | '-1' + 0 | 'pancakes11' + 0 |
+-------------------+----------+------------------+
|           192.168 |       -1 |                0 |
+-------------------+----------+------------------+
```

So `'a1'` is zero in a numeric or boolean context because `'a'` is cannot be part of a (decimal) number.

The [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) and [`convert`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) sections of the manual may be of use.

---

PS: Don't get in the habit of using double quotes for strings, MySQL lets you get away with it but many databases won't. Single quotes are used for quoting string literals in SQL.